# Why is font rendering worse in Windows 10 than in 7/8.1

Tags: windows, fonts

Windows 10 seems to render some fonts really, really badly:

[image]

The character spacing is all over the place, and individual characters vary in width (compare all the 'L' characters) seemingly at random. Windows 7 and 8.1 seem to do a better job by making characters stick to pixel boundaries when possible.

This new font rendering looks particularly awful on low DPI displays. It's better on high DPI, but not much. What caused Microsoft to downgrade font rendering quality in this way? What purpose does it serve?

Comment: That really looks like the monitor is not set to its native resolution.

Comment: The monitor is set correctly, but that's irrelevant because this is a screenshot not a photo.